# Display available applications in Applications Lens

Tags: unity, applications-lens

On Ubuntu 16.04.1, searches in the Applications lens return installed apps but not available apps, even though `gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.ApplicationsLens display-available-apps` is `true`.
For example, search for "twitter" returns results in "Ubuntu Software" but nothing in the applications lens. Under "Filter search results" in the apps lens, there are two sources: Local apps, Software center. But Software center is no more, Ubuntu Software is the new way. So, will it be possible to display available apps later or is something missing on my system ?